# How to use range object with a worksheet object

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a simple program to merge cells in different sheet.
I wrote this code

```
 Dim ws as worksheet
 Set worksheet = sheets ("sheets2")
 ws.range (cells (1,1),cells (1,5)).merge
```

This is not working and error comes saying method range of object worksheet failed
Please help me with this
Thank you

Comment: Don't merge cells! Cause no end of problems.

Comment: You've defined `ws` and used `worksheet`... use `Set ws = Sheets("Sheets2")`.  Also `ws.range` references `Sheets2` but `cells(1,1)` references the active sheet - use `ws.cells(1,1)`.  Also..... are you sure it's `sheets2` and not `sheet2`?  Also.... don't merge cells! Causes no end of problems (use center across selection instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("sheets2")
    With ws
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 5)).Merge
    End With

End Sub
```

The range object is a bit difficult in Excel and when you are referencing to cells you should also reference to the sheet.

Take a look at the Microsoft examples, they are good:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx

Especially the third note:
*Be aware that the period in front of each occurrence of the Cells property. The period is required if the result of the preceding With statement is to be applied to the Cells property—in this case, to indicate that the cells are on worksheet one (without the period, the Cells property would return cells on the active sheet).*

Comment: @ShaiRado - in my case I simply wrote it on Notepad++

Comment: Vityata - are you telepathic?

Comment: Ha, a useful skill round here.